# Why does this exec.Command to a different opened tty not work properly

Tags: macos, vim, go, stdin, tty

Can anybody please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm trying to execute a command (opening vim in this case) that runs in a different tty, in this case /dev/ttys001, which is opened in another tab in my terminal.

Running the code below does render vim in /dev/ttys001's window, however, actually typing to stdin from that window doesn't register properly.

Any advice is much appreciated!

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    tty, err := os.OpenFile("/dev/ttys001", os.O_RDWR, os.ModePerm)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer tty.Close()

    c := exec.Command("vim")
    c.Stdin = tty
    c.Stdout = tty
    c.Stderr = tty
    if err := c.Run(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

I have also tried setting the command's SysProcAttr field with the following code but receive the error: fork/exec /usr/local/bin/vim: inappropriate ioctl for device.

```
procAttr := &syscall.SysProcAttr{
    Setpgid:    true,
    Ctty:       int(tty.Fd()),
    Foreground: true,
}
c.SysProcAttr = procAttr
```

Comment: try calling c.Wait() after.

Comment: Hey @AJPennster, I'm currently using c.Run and not c.Start and c.Run automatically calls Wait for you.

Comment: ah right, I missed that.

Comment: What happens exactly when you type in the window?

Comment: For example, usually in vim if you simply type the letter i, you are placed into insert mode whereas in this case, you can continually type the letter i, but it's just ignored and placed on the screen (not actually interacting with the vim process), but sometimes after typing enter, a command such as the letter i might actually go through. I can't pin what the issue is unfortunately.

Comment: This is the reason I was trying to work out the correct settings such as setting Foreground to true in SysProcAttr, since I think the issue is that the command does not run properly in the foreground in the separate tty instance.

Comment: If i were to do the same thing with echo "hello", i get the output but I don't get the prompt after, that indicates that the command has ended. I figure that this behaviour is specific to the terminal. I'm speculating, based on what i get when running it, that the problem has to do with incompatibility with the terminal and cmd.Run(). The terminal probably does some initialising or something of the sort before(and after) running the command. Whatever it does though, helps it with printing stdin/stdout/stderr of whatever command it is running. Go on the other hand just runs the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody who's interested, I came up with a solution, but I ended up having to use system calls instead of the os/exec package's functions.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

var tty = "/dev/ttys001"
var cmd = "vim\n"

func main() {
    ttyFile, err := os.Open(tty)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer ttyFile.Close()

    cbs, err := syscall.ByteSliceFromString(cmd)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    var eno syscall.Errno
    for _, c := range cbs {
        _, _, eno = syscall.Syscall(syscall.SYS_IOCTL,
            ttyFile.Fd(),
            syscall.TIOCSTI,
            uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&c)),
        )
        if eno != 0 {
            log.Fatalln(eno)
        }
    }
}
```